# FileOpenPicker: Can't add complex type to ContinuationData

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am not able to add a custom type to he ContinuationData in the FileOpenPicker. I can add string/int/datetime, but when I try to add my custom CustomFolder object it fails with the following exception.

```
CustomFolder TargetFolde = new CustomFolder()
FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

// Filter to include a sample subset of file types
open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

KeyValuePair<string, object> fold = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Folder", TargetFolder);
open.ContinuationData.Add(fold);
open.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
}
```

> {System.Exception: Data of this type is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8007065E)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IMap`2.Insert(K key, V
>   value)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.MapToDictionaryAdapter.Insert[K,V](IMap`2
>   _this, K key, V value)    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.MapToDictionaryAdapter.Add[K,V](K
>   key, V value)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.MapToCollectionAdapter.Add[K,V](KeyValuePair`2
>   item)    at Lockie.Shared.Util.d__1b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at Lockie.Folder.d__5.MoveNext()}

Comment: Is the CustomFolder class declared as serializable?

Comment: I tried making it with the [Serializable] attrib but the class lives in a portable class library which doesn't support this attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only basic types are allowed. WinRT does not offer a serialization mechanism like .NET

You can serialize the data yourself using XML or JSON and store that as a string.